# Как изменить дату по умолчанию в DatePicker wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, datepicker

подскажите пожалуйста, как убрать дату DatePicker wpf по умолчанию которая: 01.01.0001 и установить собственную дату по умолчанию допустим 01.01.2000. Спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположим у нас есть стандартный класс нашего объекта:

```
public class ItemViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

И в основной ViewModel есть привязанная коллекция:

```
public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items { get; set; }
```

В разметке стандартный DataGrid с автогенерацией:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
```

Вот если у вас такой же вариант, то тут достаточно переписать свойство с датой, добавив ему значение по умолчанию:

```
public DateTime Date { get; set; } = new DateTime(2020,1,1);
```

---

Другой вариант, это установить значение по умолчанию через XAML.
Для этого у привязок существуют свойства [FallbackValue](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingbase.fallbackvalue) и [TargetNullValue](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingbase.targetnullvalue).

Сделаем простенькую разметку:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Имя" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Дата" Binding="{Binding Data, FallbackValue='2019.01.02'}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Результат получим примерно такой:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datepicker.text?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Controls_DatePicker_Text

```
<my:DatePicker SelectedDate="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}"/> // поменяйте на свою дату

// надо добавить ссылку

xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"

// или так

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    dpDate.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today;            
}
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое!!!

Comment: @Евгений если ответ помог,то отметьте его как "ответ" :)